# Apply ODBC in DLL file for SSIS script

Tags: c#, sql-server, dll, ssis, odbc

I am attempting to remove the redundancy in the script task (C#, .NET Framework 2.0) for 15 SSIS packages developed in SQL Server 2008 R2.  I am attempting to remove the redundancy by creating a DLL assembly that is referenced.  The redundant code applies an ODBC connection.  So, getting to the point, I was able to create the DLL file using Visual Studio 2008, set it up with a strong key and add it to the GAC.  But when I run the SSIS package applying the script with a reference to the custom DLL, I am seeing the following familiar error:

"**ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized**."

This only takes place when I try to apply a method defined in the class set up in the referenced assembly.  Resolving this, according to other similar issues, is to assign the connection to the SQLCommand, assigning to the constructor or property.  But my situation involves the error taking place when the connection is actually defined in a referenced DLL.  I have never tried this before and do not know if it is possible.  To assist, I've first provided the DLL code below.

```
using System; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Data.Odbc; 
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper; 
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

namespace XXXX.SSIS.Common
{
public class SQL
{
    protected IDTSConnectionManager100 connMgr;
    protected OdbcConnection oOdbcConnection;
    protected bool bDebugMode;

    public bool LookupExistence(string sSQL)
    {
        bool bReturn;
        OdbcCommand oOdbcCommand;
        OdbcDataReader oDataReader;

        bReturn = false;

        //LogMessage("Lookup SQL", sSQL.ToString(), "", bDebugMode);

        oOdbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(sSQL, oOdbcConnection);
        oOdbcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        oDataReader = oOdbcCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (oDataReader.HasRows)
        {
            bReturn = true;
        }
        oDataReader.Close();

        return bReturn;
    }

    public void ExecuteDML(string sSQL)
    {
        OdbcCommand oOdbcCommand;

        //LogMessage("DML SQL", sSQL.ToString(), "", bDebugMode);

        oOdbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(sSQL, oOdbcConnection);
        oOdbcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        oOdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
}
```

The main script applying the above DLL code looks like the following.  I have the two methods (LookupExistence and ExecuteDML)in the SQL region commented out, as it is they that I am trying to apply from the referenced DLL instead.  **The error message only appears when running the SSIS package if I call them using cls.LookupExistence and cls.ExecuteDML.  But if I remove the "cls." prefacing the method calls and uncomment the SQL region below, the SSIS package runs successfully.  My guess is that the initialization for the connection property somehow needs to be passed from the main script to the referenced DLL, but I am not sure how to do that.**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using XXXX.SSIS.Common;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
protected IDTSConnectionManager100 connMgr;
protected OdbcConnection oOdbcConnection;
protected bool bDebugMode;
protected string sSqlLookup;
protected string sSqlInsert;
protected string sSqlUpdate;
protected string sSqlDelete;

public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();
    /*
      Add your code here for preprocessing or remove if not needed
    */
    bDebugMode = Variables.varDebugMode;
    sSqlLookup = Variables.varOdbcLookup;
    sSqlInsert = Variables.varOdbcInsert;
    sSqlUpdate = Variables.varOdbcUpdate;
    sSqlDelete = Variables.varOdbcDelete;
}

public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();
    /*
      Add your code here for postprocessing or remove if not needed
      You can set read/write variables here, for example:
      Variables.MyIntVar = 100
    */
}

public override void Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
{
    while (Buffer.NextRow())
    {
        Input0_ProcessInputRow(Buffer);
    }
}

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    /*
      Add your code here
    */
    string sSqlDml;
    string sLookup;

    Ball.SSIS.Common.SQL cls = new Ball.SSIS.Common.SQL();

    sLookup = String.Format(sSqlLookup, Row.ABAN8.ToString());

    LogMessage("Lookup Built", sLookup, "", bDebugMode);

    if (Row.modifiedflag == "3")
    {
        sSqlDml = sSqlDelete;
    }
    else
    {
        if (cls.LookupExistence(sLookup))
        {
            //Update
            sSqlDml = sSqlUpdate;
        }
        else
        {
            //Insert
            sSqlDml = sSqlInsert;
        }

    }


    LogMessage("sSqlDml", sSqlDml, "", bDebugMode);
    sSqlDml = String.Format(sSqlDml, 
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString(),
                            Row.xxxx.ToString()
                            );
    LogMessage("sSqlDml Formatted", sSqlDml, "", bDebugMode);
    LogMessage("ExecuteDML", "Executing DML statement.", "", bDebugMode);
    cls.ExecuteDML(sSqlDml);
}

#region SQL
 //private bool LookupExistence(string sSQL)
//{
//    bool bReturn;
//    OdbcCommand oOdbcCommand;
//    OdbcDataReader oDataReader;

//    bReturn = false;

//    LogMessage("Lookup SQL", sSQL.ToString(), "", bDebugMode);

//    oOdbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(sSQL, oOdbcConnection);
//    oOdbcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

//    oDataReader = oOdbcCommand.ExecuteReader();
//    if (oDataReader.HasRows)
//    {
//        bReturn = true;
//    }
//    oDataReader.Close();

//    return bReturn;
//}

//private void ExecuteDML(string sSQL)
//{
//    OdbcCommand oOdbcCommand;

//    LogMessage("DML SQL", sSQL.ToString(), "", bDebugMode);

//    oOdbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(sSQL, oOdbcConnection);
//    oOdbcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
//    oOdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
//}    #endregion

#region CONNECTIONS
public override void AcquireConnections(object Transaction)
{
    connMgr = this.Connections.QadConnection;
    oOdbcConnection = (OdbcConnection)connMgr.AcquireConnection(null);
}

public override void ReleaseConnections()
{
    connMgr.ReleaseConnection(oOdbcConnection);
}
#endregion

#region LOGGING
private void LogMessage(string tableName, string fieldName, string fieldValue, bool bDebug)
{
    if (bDebug)
    {
        bool bTrash = false;
        int iTrash = 1;
        this.ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(iTrash, tableName, fieldName, fieldValue, iTrash, ref bTrash);
    }
}
#endregion

}
```

Thanks in advance and let me know if you require additional information.

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason for the connection error was because the connection was not being opened in the DLL.  Of course, this also required closing it as well.  To do this in a cleaner manner, I applied the "using" command with a try-catch.  Listed below is the code for the two updated methods.

```
public bool LookupExistence(string sSQL)
    {
        //bool bReturn;

        // Applying the "using" both opens and closes the connection.
        // There is no need to dispose of the connection with this approach.
        using (OdbcConnection oOdbcConnection = new OdbcConnection())
        {
            OdbcCommand oOdbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(); 
            //bool bReturn;

            //Open the connection and execute the insert command.
            try
            {
                bool bReturn;
                OdbcDataReader oDataReader;

                bReturn = false;

                oOdbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(sSQL, oOdbcConnection);
                oOdbcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                oDataReader = oOdbcCommand.ExecuteReader();
                if (oDataReader.HasRows)
                {
                    bReturn = true;
                }

                return bReturn;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                bool bReturn = false;
                return bReturn;
            }
        }
    }

   public void ExecuteDML(string sSQL)
    {
        // Applying the "using" both opens and closes the connection.
        // There is no need to dispose of the connection with this approach.
        using (OdbcConnection oOdbcConnection = new OdbcConnection())
        {
            OdbcCommand oOdbcCommand = new OdbcCommand();

            //Open the connection and execute the insert command.
            try
            {
                oOdbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(sSQL, oOdbcConnection);
                oOdbcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                oOdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```

Thanks.